# Executing bash script on server via PHP after clicking on a button in browser doesn't work

Tags: php, ajax, bash, button

I'm trying to create a web-page that after a click on the button would perform a bash script on the server side. What am I doing wrong? It seems that my shell script is just not being run for some reason... however, if I just perform

```
php test.php
```

command on the server side, the script runs successfully... would greatly appreciate if someone helps me figure out what exactly my mistake is.
I've looked through similar questions asked before, but still can't get it to work.

Part of index.php responsible for the button:

```
<button type="button">Click Me</button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("button").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url:"test.php", //the page containing php script
    type: "POST", //request type
    success:function(result){
    alert(result);
    }
  });
});
})
</script>
```

test.php :

```
<?php
shell_exec("/var/www/html/tester.sh");
?>
```

tester.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash

#here something will happen

touch /tmp/testfile
```

Comment: Probably the user account under which your web server runs does not have access to that file

Comment: Which user owns `tester.sh`? and whats its permissions? running via cli most likely works because your not running the file as www-data, but instead the owner of the file

Comment: setting file owner and group to www-data doesn't seem to help... tried changing permissions to -rwxr--r-- www-data:www-data with no improvement @Nick

Comment: Is `www-data` the actual account for your webserver? and what happens if you set permissions to 777?

Comment: it is `www-data`, yes. 777 - no changes

Comment: Does your alert box pop up? If you change your PHP to `echo shell_exec("/var/www/html/tester.sh");` what is in the alert box?

Comment: @Nick there's no alert, so I assume the problem is within `index.php` somewhere?

Comment: @0lesya probably although maybe your button click handler is never being called. What happens if you put an alert before the ajax call?

Comment: after I do smth like ...
`$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("after ready");
$("button").click(function(){
        alert("after click");
  $.ajax({`
I get the _after ready_ alert when opening the page, and after clicking onto the button, _after click_ alert.. @Nick

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189035/discussion-between-nick-and-0lesya).

Answer (score -2):

you forget a ";" at the last line of your js

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("button").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url:"test.php", //the page containing php script
    type: "POST", //request type
    success:function(result){
    alert(result);
    }
  });
});
});
</script>
```